# How to edit field in Angular reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want my field to be editable. So when I change one of these fields I want it to be changed. See code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2?file=app/app.component.html

Try firstName. Change the name to one of yours, and press accept. The old one comes back again ... I want the new one to be chosen for me.
I have also cancel button. If user wan't to change and only cancel change.
Main thinks in on accept() function...

I need to know which exact field has been changed and remember it. Maybe I can do it with if but what if for example 10 fields it would be 10 ifs and very bad code.

```
  editing = {
    given_name: false,
    family_name: false,
    nickname: false,
    gender: false
  };

  user = {
    given_name: "Ted",
    family_name: "Mosley",
    nickname: "Tedster",
    gender: "Male"
  };

  form = new FormGroup({
    given_name: new FormControl(this.user.given_name, Validators.required),
    family_name: new FormControl(this.user.family_name, Validators.required),
    nickname: new FormControl(this.user.nickname),
    gender: new FormControl(this.user.gender, Validators.required)
  });

  toggleEdit(attribute) {
    console.log(attribute);
    this.editing[attribute] = !this.editing[attribute];
  }

  accept() {
    this.editing.given_name = true; // or family_name or nickname  or age ....
  }




  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'editing': editing.given_name}">
    <label for="number">First Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="given_name"
      id="given_name"
      placeholder="Jane"
    />
    <div class="value">{{user.given_name}}</div>
    <button (click)="toggleEdit('given_name')">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="accept('given_name')">Accept</button>
    <button (click)="editing.given_name = true">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your `user` object after calling `accept()`
Add below line in your `accept()`

```
this.user[attribute] = this.form.value[attribute];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do that easily by using `setValue` and `get`. 
To cancel, your code should be like =>

```
this.form.get(param.toString()).setValue(this.user[param]);// for cancel button
```

For accept button code should be

```
this.user[param]=this.form.get(param).value;
```

**Note:** I have updated your code in stackblitz => [Update Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2-j8b2jb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Ok work but one more question, how to show edit icon only on hover mouse ? After it I will vote up

Comment: @MichaelTomas Where you want show edit icon inside edit button?

Comment: currently the edit button is displayed without hover. For example, I just want to display the edit button on the hover row. Without being visible to me non stop just on hover. Hover on row example given_name  or  familiy_name

Comment: @MichaelTomas On your request I have updated the [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2-j8b2jb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Please check now. Check the First Name Part.